# Open problems in continued fractions theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, big-list, continued-fractions, open-problems

I propose to collect here open problems from the theory of continued fractions. Any types of continued fractions are welcome.

Comment: What's the question here?  The title and answers look like you are after a list of open problems or conjectures on continued fractions, but the body of the question focuses 100% on one conjecture.  If you want a list, it would be clearer to ask for that in the body of the question and move the current content to an answer.

Comment: @Henry Cohn Thank you for your advice. The answer was removed from the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory, F21, attributes to Bohuslav Divis the conjecture that in each real quadratic field there is an irrational with all partial quotients 1 or 2; more generally, same question but with 1 and 2 replaced by any pair of distinct positive integers.

Answer (score 12):

[Zaremba's Conjecture](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.3776):

> every integer appears as the denominator of a finite continued fraction whose partial quotients are bounded by an absolute constant.

Answer (score 8):

From M. Waldschmidt, "Open Diophantine Problems" (Moscow Mathematical Journal vol. 4, no. 1, 2004, pp. 245-305):

- Does there exist a real algebraic number of degree $\geq 3$ with bounded partial quotients?
- Does there exist a real algebraic number of degree $\geq 3$ with unbounded partial quotients?

Answer (score 6):

Find fixed points (mod 1) of Minkowski's question mark function, see [A058914](http://oeis.org/A058914) from "The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences". This picture [image: MinkowskisQuestionMarkFunction]

is taken from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinkowskisQuestionMarkFunction.html 
It shows that there is only one positive fixed point (mod 1) less than 1/2. It is approximately 0.42037. Does this constant have a closed-form expression?

Answer (score 6):

> Hermite's problem is an open problem in mathematics posed by Charles Hermite in 1848. He asked for a way of expressing real numbers as sequences of natural numbers, such that the sequence is eventually periodic precisely when the original number is a cubic irrational.

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%27s_problem

Answer (score 5):

Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory, F21, attributes to Leo Moser the conjecture that there is a constant $c$ such that every $n$ can be expressed as $n=a+b$ in such a way that the sum of the partial quotients of $a/b$ is less than $c\log n$.

Answer (score 4):

It is known that (see [J.W. Porter, On a theorem of
Heilbronn](http://journals.cambridge.org/abstract_S0025579300004459))
$$H(b)=\dfrac{1}{\varphi(b)}\sum\limits_{1\le a\le b\atop(a,b)=1}\ell(a/b)=
\dfrac{2\log 2}{\zeta(2)}\cdot\log
b+C_P-1+O_\varepsilon(b^{-1/6+\varepsilon}),$$ where
$\ell(a/b)$ is a length of standart continued fraction
expansion and $C_P$ is [Porter's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PortersConstant.html). Averaging
over numerators and denominators one can prove  asymptotic
formula for the variance. Let
$$E(R)=\dfrac{2}{R(R+1)}\sum\limits_{b\le
R}\sum\limits_{a\le b}\ell(a/b)
$$
and $${D}(R)=\dfrac{2}{R(R+1)}\sum\limits_{b\le
R}\sum\limits_{a\le b}\left( \ell(a/b)-E(R)\right)^2.
$$ Then (see [D. Hensley, The Number of Steps in the Euclidean Algorithm](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X84710882))
$${D}(R)=D_1\cdot\log R+o(\log R).
$$
But if denominator is fixed then for the variance only
right oder bound is known (see [Bykovskii V.A., Estimate
for dispersion of lengths of continued fractions](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10958-007-0378-9)):
$$\dfrac{1}{b}\sum\limits_{a=1}^{b}\left(\ell\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)-
\dfrac{2\log2}{\zeta(2)}\log b\right)^2\ll\log b.$$

> Conjecture:
>   $$\dfrac{1}{\varphi(b)}\sum\limits_{1\le a\le b\atop(a,b)=1}(\ell(a/b)-H(b))^2=D_1\log b+o(\log b).$$

Answer (score 4):

A collection of [Open problems in geometry of continued fractions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01450) by Oleg Karpenkov.